# android swipe and avoid refreshing recyclerview items

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want to calculate the total cost once without repeating it every time we swipe the products

android swipe and avoid refreshing recyclerview items

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
List<CartModel> cartModels;
float total;
public CartAdapter(Context context, List<CartModel> cartModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cartModels = cartModels;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_product_layout, parent, false));
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context).load(cartModels.get(position).getProductImg()).into(holder.productImg);
    holder.name.setText(cartModels.get(position).getProductName());
    holder.price.setText(cartModels.get(position).getProductPrice());
    holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(cartModels.get(position).getProductQuantity()));

    total += Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(holder.price.getText()));

    Intent intent = new Intent("MyCart");
    intent.putExtra("total", total);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cartModels.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView productImg;
    TextView name, price, quantity;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        productImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_img);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
    }
}
```

}

Picture showing before and after swipe screen
[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do any calculations in OnBindViewHolder(). That function is called every time you scroll up and down as views are recycled. Instead, I would suggest just calculating the total on initialization of the adapter

```
public CartAdapter(Context context, List<CartModel> cartModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cartModels = cartModels;
    for (CartModel model : cartModels) {
        total += model.getProductPrice();
    }
    // Set total textview

}
```

Comment: I implemented this, but it only counts the products that appeared at the beginning and after scrolling the screen it does not count the rest of the products below

Comment: @YousefHashem are you adding more items to the list somewhere other than initialization? If so just make an add function where each time you add an item to the array add the price to the total